# How do you drop multiple messages from the sys.messages table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any way to drop multiple messages in the sys.messages view in one operation?

For example, if I create 10 messages using the `sp_addmessage` stored procedure.

```
EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50001, @msgtext = 'This is the first message.'
EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50002, @msgtext = 'This is the second message.'
...
```

Is there any way to remove all of these messages at once without making 10 calls to `sp_dropmessage` or using `sp_reconfigure` to allow ad-hoc queries against the view?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know if there's any way (for example) to drop multiple error messages in one go without calling `sp_dropmessage` 10 times. This is if (and only if) I needed to renumber some custom error messages.

Comment: OK. What is the problem to run it in a loop from 50001 to 50010?

Comment: That didn't even cross my mind... now I feel like a complete idiot. :/